# CheckListBox Columns > 0 scroll vertically

Tags: delphi, vcl, tchecklistbox

How do I make CheckListBox with columns > 0 scroll **vertically**? Maybe someone can help me to hack it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ListBox columns are not true columns, like in a ListView for instance. They are more like word-wrapping in Edit controls. There is only 1 column of data in a ListBox, and when the data reaches the lower edge of the ListBox, the remaining data "wraps" to the next column, and so on, for as many columns as are configured. So, you can't really scroll *vertically* in that situation, or else the columns won't make much sense. Maybe a `TCheckListBox` isn't the best control for your situation, a `TListView` in `vsReport` mode with checkboxes enabled might make more sense instead?

Comment: @RemyL
For me not logical that if I set only 2 columns why it becomes to 3, 4 etc. I believe developers created this component in wrong way :)  But it's ok, not a big problem. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Well, I might not have explained the behavior exactly correct. But either way, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-box-styles) is very clear that *vertical* scrolling is not supported: "*`LBS_MULTICOLUMN` Specifies a multi-column list box that is scrolled **horizontally**. ... A list box with the `LBS_MULTICOLUMN` style **cannot scroll vertically** it ignores any `WM_VSCROLL` messages it receives...*"